# Error show: Assertion failed: child==_child is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

Someone can help me. I have no idea about this error. When I enter this page this error show. When I check at the console all error is the same. Hope someone can help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code

Comment: How to show code. I don't know which part in vscode is related to this error.

Comment: Instead of the red screen you want some kind of UI to appear. You need to share the code that describes this UI